# Why my Cloud Run got an Broken Pipe error?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, sqlalchemy, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

I got an error on my Cloud Run, in my log it said `Broken Pipe` error, and when I check it which line that got an error on my Code, it on my `db2.comit()`. My cloud run always run well from 6 month ago without any error, but now got this error.

So here are the detail from the log.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 385, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 45, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 190, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 111, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 181, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 159, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/cors.py", line 78, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 566, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 227, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 41, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 188, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 135, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
  File "/app/api/endpoints.py", line 48, in detect
    db2.commit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1042, in commit
    self.transaction.commit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 504, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 483, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2523, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2664, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2624, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 422, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 586, in execute
    persistence.save_obj(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 205, in save_obj
    for (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 373, in _organize_states_for_save
    for state, dict_, mapper, connection in _connections_for_states(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1602, in _connections_for_states
    connection = uowtransaction.transaction.connection(base_mapper)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 314, in connection
    return self._connection_for_bind(bind, execution_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 421, in _connection_for_bind
    conn = self._parent._connection_for_bind(bind, execution_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 433, in _connection_for_bind
    conn = bind._contextual_connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2304, in _contextual_connect
    self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, None),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2338, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 364, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 809, in _checkout
    result = pool._dialect.do_ping(fairy.connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 560, in do_ping
    cursor.execute(self._dialect_specific_select_one)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pg8000/core.py", line 340, in execute
    self._c.execute_unnamed(self, "begin transaction")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pg8000/core.py", line 1214, in execute_unnamed
    self.handle_messages(cursor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pg8000/core.py", line 1377, in handle_messages
    code, data_len = ci_unpack(self._read(5))
struct.error: unpack_from requires a buffer of at least 5 bytes for unpacking 5 bytes at offset 0 (actual buffer size is 0)
```

And this is my line of code that occurs the error.

```
    except Exception as e:  # noqa
        log = orm.LogPredictStatus(customer_id=customer_id, status_code=500, car_attribute=car.dict(), price=None, source='TEST', created_at=time_zone_jakarta)
        db2.add(log)
        db2.commit()
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=500,
            detail=str(e),
        )
```

Comment: From  what little information in terms of code I see,  I am guessing that something within ```log``` isn't conforming to what is expected out of the elements.   Try debugging what ```log``` contains.  There's an empty buffer field somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the response @ewong ,Okay it solved now, it was caused by the inserting method on my script.